# UICollectionView cell leaves huge gaps all settings set to 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi there i have a slight problem with my `UICollectionView`. i don't currently have any settings set for spacing yet i seem to have a huge gap between my cells of which is very annoying if would be helpful if someone could tell me how to resolve this? id assume its something very simple.

Below is an example of whats happening to my `CollectionViewCells`:

[image]

Custom cell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *IconImage;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *IconLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *IconDescription;

@end
```

groupsviewcontroller.m

```
#import "GroupsViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface GroupsViewController ()
{
    NSArray *arrayOfImages;
    NSArray *arrayOfDescriptions;
}

@end

@implementation GroupsViewController
{
    NSString *reuseIdentifier;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    reuseIdentifier= @"SmallIcon";
    [[self GroupsCollectionView]setDataSource:self];
    [[self GroupsCollectionView]setDelegate:self];



    arrayOfImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"sin.png", nil];

    arrayOfDescriptions = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Sin", nil];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayOfDescriptions count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[cell IconImage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
    [[cell IconLabel]setText:[arrayOfDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    return cell;
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    //Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)cellToggleAction:(id)sender {
//need to add toggle button to toggle between three different views

    //small icon
    //list view
    //large icon
}


@end
```

Comment: Did you create your `UICollectionView` programmatically?

Comment: Yes would you like the code?

Comment: Please, otherwise it is pretty hard for us to help you :p

Comment: Edited to show code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should check your `CustomCell` class, see if any size constraint is applied. Simply set your cell's background as some color and the actual cell size will be highlighted.

2) Use `(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to help yourself set the proper cell size. This func comes with `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` :)

Comment: You sir are amazing! Such a simple thing to miss but something you would hardly look for, i simply had a constraint added to my custom cell in interface builder. Thanks once Again

Comment: @LeeSugden You are welcome, please mark this as answer if it solved your problem  XP